# how can i scroll pages down from menu on the top

Tags: jquery, html

I am new here and, I am new to jquery as well. I am trying to make a website with `background-fixed` with a image and four links on the top to go to each page like: about, portfolio, contact, gallery. It should be when I click on about, a page drop down, and again upon clicking, same for second link and so on for all the links.
I have written following codes in html and css. I am done with one page down but don't know how to add more pages.

Here is my css:

```
body{
    margin:auto;
    padding:auto; 
}
#page{
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-image:url('done3.jpg');
}
#panel{
    padding:50px;display:none;
}
#panel 
{
    padding:300px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#e5eecc;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3; 
}
#flip
{
    width:100px;
    padding:15px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:pink;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

        <script> 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#flip").click(function(){
                    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>demo</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <div id="flip">about us</div>
            <div id="panel">about us</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the current scroll position with `$(window).scrollTop(positionInPixels);` and get an elements position on the website with `.offset().top`. Putting that together and assuming `$link` is your link and `$target` is the target you want to scroll to:

```
$link.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(window).scrollTop() != $target.offset().top) {
        $(window).scrollTop($target.offset().top);
    } else {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: it works, wowww.thanks. can i also slide it from other side? for example from right side to left? should i need to chande slidedown() or something else

Comment: For horizontal scrolling, you could use `scrollLeft` instead of `scrollTop` and `offset().left` instead of `offset().top`!

Answer (score 1):

If you will have more "flips" then you should make a flip class for CSS and give each one a unique ID.

CSS:

```
<style>
body
{
margin:auto;
padding:auto; 
}
#page 
{
width:1000px;
height:1000px;
border:1px solid red;
background-image:url('done3.jpg');
}
.panel
{padding:50px;display:none;
}
.panel 
{
padding:300px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3; 
}
.flip
{
width:100px;
padding:15px;
text-align:center;
background-color:pink;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flip" id="flip">about us</div><div class="flip" id="flip2">about us2</div>
<div class="panel" id="panel">content</div>

<div class="panel"  id="panel2">content2</div>
```

You also need to add more to your javascript on what to do when it is clicked.  Here is a sample but you should make it more of a function so you don't copy and paste it for every "flip".

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#flip").click(function(){
$("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#flip2").click(function(){
$("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
});

});
</script>
```

Here is a partially working version.  There can be many enhancements, but hopefully enough to get you started.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#flipabout").click(function(){
$("#panelabout").slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#flipportfolio").click(function(){
$("#panelportfolio").slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#flipcontact").click(function(){
$("#panelcontact").slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#flipgallery").click(function(){
$("#panelgallery").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>demo</title>
<style>
body
{
margin:auto;
padding:auto; 
}
#page 
{
width:1000px;
height:1000px;
border:1px solid red;
background-image:url('done3.jpg');
}
.panel
{padding:50px;display:none;
}
.panel 
{
padding:300px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3; 
}
.flip
{
width:100px;
padding:15px;
text-align:center;
background-color:pink;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div  id="page">
<div class="flip" id="flipabout">about us</div>
<div class="flip" id="flipportfolio">portfolio</div>
<div class="flip" id="flipcontact">contact</div>
<div class="flip" id="flipgallery">gallery</div>
<div class="panel" id="panelabout">about...</div>
<div class="panel"  id="panelportfolio">Portfolio...</div>
<div class="panel"  id="panelcontact">contact...</div>
<div class="panel"  id="panelgallery">gallery....</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```